# Syncing files to device (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Tags: flutter

After updating to `Flutter version 1.17.4` I started getting

> Syncing files to device (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

and

> Performing hot restart... (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

it eventually finishes but takes 2.5-5 minutes which is a productivity killer.
I'm not sure it's related to the update though, because downgrading doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason changing the name of the flutter SDK folder fixes it, I changed it from `flutter` to `_flutter`

I don't know why this is working.